# JavaSpaces Notify Handler Method

Tags: java, callback, notify, javaspaces

I am trying to implement a handler method which can a notify depending on the parameters that are passed into the space. E.g i have the following code which puts a template into space where tab is the name of a room:

```
private void createMessageListener(String tab) {
        // create the exporter
        Exporter myDefaultExporter =
                new BasicJeriExporter (TcpServerEndpoint.getInstance(0),
                        new BasicILFactory(), false, true);

        try {
            // register this as a remote object
            // and get a reference to the 'stub'
            msgListener = (RemoteEventListener) myDefaultExporter.export(this);

            // add the listener
            Message template = new Message(tab);
            regMsgs = space.notify(template, null, this.msgListener, Lease.FOREVER, null);
            seqMsgs = regMsgs.getSequenceNumber();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Is there a way to find out what the parameter has been passed in for the notify method, when trying to handle the event registration as shown below??

```
public void notify(RemoteEvent arg0) throws UnknownEventException,
    RemoteException {

        ///Find out the parameter in the notification and then handle?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Solved this problem by checking against the EventListenerID

public void notify(RemoteEvent arg0) throws UnknownEventException,
    RemoteException {

        arg0.getID();//<<Compared to a local storgae of ID's
                          then handle the results
                     

        }
    }